# i want binding context list but not working

Tags: ibm-bpm

**I custom object:**

[image]

I want to fill the object but not working.

**My Code:**

[image]

```
  var BindingMainCat = context.binding.get("value");
                 BindingMainCat.set("AllPaymentsList[0].id", invoice_id);
                 BindingMainCat.set("AllPaymentsList[0].amount", inputs[i].value);
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please add code not image of the code

Answer (score 0):

Accessors in coachview bound variables do not support complex navigation with dots and brackets. Once you obtain list itself you can use `add()`, `remove()` and `put()` operations on list items. You are allowed to use `get()` and `set()` on attributes of the list but not items themselves - see IBM documentation for ["List operations" of binding](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTDH_8.5.7/com.ibm.wbpm.wle.editor.doc/topics/rbindingdata.html). For example:

```
var list = this.context.binding.get("value");
var item0 = list.get(0);
item0.set("id", invoice_id);
item0.set("amount", inputs[i].value);
```

Also you can replace element of list with new one:

```
var list = this.context.binding.get("value");
var newItem0 = {id: invoice_id, amount: inputs[i].value};
list.put(0, newItem0);
```

Note that the final content of the list is the same but change notifications are different. In first example there will be two events about item properties changed, in second example there will be single event about list change - see [`bind()` and `bindAll()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTDH_8.5.7/com.ibm.wbpm.wle.editor.doc/topics/rbindingdata.html) documentation.

Be also warned that on each step you can encounter empty values, if coachview does not have any binding then `this.context.binding` is undefined, if bound variable is null then `this.context.binding.get("value")` is null, if list has no items then `list.get(0)` is undefined etc.